# How to recreate form with dynamic fields for edit in react antd (rc-forms)

Tags: reactjs, antd, rc-form

After using antd form component (which depends on `rc-form`) for creating a form, I need to avail an edit form as well, I can't find any resources on how to initialize the antd form with the form values I have (especially the dynamic fields)

I found that using `form.setFieldsInitialValue(theEditValues);` will correctly initialize some of the form fields with the data correctly (for example, the dropdown with multiple select), but not the normal dropdowns ***& most importantly, all the dynamic fields are not created***, giving a warning that you can't set field data before creating a field

So is there a preferred way to handle the edit scenario? so that:

1- To recreate the dynamic fields based on the submitted data before

2- To sync the whole form with the submitted data

I have added [a sandbox to show what I mean](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-hill-gryjq), mainly if I have form values & I want to initialize the form with the dynamic fields with the values given

### Note:

We need to handle a generic case where the user entered any number of dynamic fields and we wanna avail an edit form page with the given info

### Update:

I have updated the example [in a new sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-snowflake-f7jop) to show what is meant by handling the values dynamically, I don't know the dynamic input in the edit scenario, it can be one field or plenty, so after retreiving the data from the api, it should be injected in the form programtically using `form.setFieldsValue` (just like how it can be handled for the static fields)

Comment: did that work? my solution below?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I have updated the question, sorry didn't notice that your comment was here, I provided a new sandbox because yours solve it for a static case & I didn't want to change the initial sandbox if it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated code https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-sun-e57dm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Here are things to do

1. You need to initialize `id` with 2 since you need 2 initial fields.
2. You need to initialize `keys` field value with two values in array instead of `[]` like

```js
getFieldDecorator("keys", { initialValue: [0, 1] });
```

3. assign initial value to available fields using this

```js
getFieldDecorator(`names[${k}]`, {
  validateTrigger: ["onChange", "onBlur"],
  initialValue: valueOfFormToEdit[k] || '',
  rules: [
    {
      required: true,
      whitespace: true,
      message: "Please input passenger's name or delete this field."
    }
  ]
})
```

## Update

Updated sandbox for new *requirements* :D

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-kirch-9gq1b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thank you, but here you assume knowing that it is only 2 fields, it was only an example, I wanna handle a generic case where the user entered any number of fields and we wanna give him an edit form page with his info

Comment: you can simply initialize the value of that number with user input

Comment: insetad of global variable, make it state variable

Comment: Thanks Zohaib, even handling the static case, the demo you have put in your answer does not have any fields preloaded, I am trying to make it have the fields with the values (just like an edit scenario), so still something is missing..

Comment: @AhmedElkoussy I added wrong url. Look at the updated link

Comment: try to open the link in incognito, the link still doesn't work, I think you need to press ctrl + s to update ur sandbox & save it , it doesn't autosave like stackblitz

Comment: updated. try this now https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-sun-e57dm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: This last update for the sandbox works for a predefined number of dynamic fields, I am working on switching this to a dynamic handling, I didn't accept the answer waiting for other ideas on handling this dynamically, thank you

Comment: @AhmedElkoussy Can you update sandbox to let me know what do you mean by dynamic initial values? How you are getting those initial values? any input, from some api? how